# What is needed write an interface to Microsoft Dynamics GP web services?

Tags: web-services, integration

We've went ahead and purchased Microsoft Dynamics (see [edit history](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/230168/revisions) for why) in order to write 2 functions to interact with one tiny part of it to fulfill one big need.

What I want to know is, from other programmers who have integrated their software with MS Dynamics GP. Is there any way to connect with it (fully) without having to write an interface in C#?

We want to use GP SOAP services so we can communicate to it from Delphi and eventually Java, but it seems like the only way we're going to be able to maximize it's usefulness is to write some sort of middleware program in C#.

Comment: meta note [tag:dynamics] is the stackoverflow tag for microsoft dynamics, I wanted to use it here, but it wouldn't let me, I didn't think it was a big enough deal to bring up on meta.

Comment: Ask around in the GP community: http://community.dynamics.com/gp/default.aspx

Comment: For the record, though my experience customizing GP is fairly limited, we ultimately wrote our own API around certain portions of the database to facilitate our API needs -- this was after having used the GP SOAP service and found it recalculating values we didn't want recalculated.

Comment: @svidgen do you remember what your place had to do to get it's hands on a test copy of GP, do you absolutely have to buy it just to code to it? It's just painful since it costs as much as many shiny new Delphis.

Comment: We were already using a copy when I was asked to start customizing it. If you're writing customizations for a client, you either need to join PartnerSource (no idea how to do that) or get a copy of GP from your client (potentially via CustomerSource).

Comment: If you contact a Microsoft GP Partner, most would install GP for you with the just the GP test company. Then you would have an environment, in-house, that you could use. I don't think that violates anything or would cost you anything other than their time to set it up. Not all partners would be so willing, but I think having a relationship with a developer would be a good thing for the partner. Talk to the customers you have written stuff for and find out who their partner is, and then build a relationship.

Comment: You may want to look at getting a [MSDN subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/). If I recall correctly GP is available there. I haven't done the math but I imagine a MSDN subscription would be less than a GP license with the added bonus of access to the rest of Microsoft's software collection.

Comment: @Mike sorry, I forgot to edit the question when I put the bounty on it.  We got past the whole on-the-fence about buying it because the boss wants to use it in house for our own accounting (and dogfooding) purposes.  Now, we just want to connect to it from something outside the CLR.

Comment: @PeterTurner I'm curious. What'd you end up doing for this?

Comment: @svidgen quit my job, working in Fitchburg now :)   We went with the C# option completely out of necessity since the WSDL that was supposed to work with Delphi absolutely refused to not suck.   I can't remember why Java didn't work.  Might have been "found hard and left untried"

Comment: @PeterTurner Ha ... ok then!

Answer (score 3):

The preferred approach towards customizing the Great Plains (GP) is to access data via database.

You can write a application in any programming language you are comfortable with which can connect to a database. This is a risky approach though, but there are developers customizing GP in that fashion. The schema details for the GP database is not well documented. However, you can [buy some documentation on it from this site](http://www.gp-dynamics.com/) or learn by discussing in a GP specific forum on what others might know. Otherwise, as in the comments to your question, you can connect with other developers in the GP community in the links posted in comments.

In a [blog post](http://sandipdjadhav.blogspot.in/2010/04/types-of-integration-method-with.html), Other methods for connecting to GP could are listed -

- Microsoft Integration Manager which uses excel sheets and delimited file
- Dynamic GP Web Services which uses eConnect API to retrieve data.

Hope this helps. Do post the way the approach you have undertaken to benefit community.

Comment: would you mind explaining more on what these resources do and why do you recommend these as answering the question asked? ["Link-only answers"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info "what's this") are not quite welcome at Stack Exchange

Comment: @gnat, I have expanded the content to include the idea. However, I have included the Link for further reference.

Comment: You need to tell us *what those links are*, and make sure that if those links ever went away, your answer wouldn't be completely useless. For example, you could quote from the blog post as to what options there are (summarize them here), then help the OP understand how some of those options might be a good fit. Don't just link.

Comment: @Martijn, I have expanded the content in the link as bulleted list, which I found relevant to the question. Please let me know if the above needs more polishing

Comment: I posted my comment long after that edit; it still applies.

Comment: @Martijn, I have acted on the comments, Do let me know if this acceptable by standards.

Comment: It's a lot better already; do you have any affiliation with the GP-Dynamics site? I see that that exists mostly to sell documentation; if you stand to benefit from people clicking on the link, please do disclose so.

Comment: No I do not have any affiliation with GP-Dynamics site. I got link from Google search.

Comment: The first sentence of your answer  "The preferred approach towards customizing the Great Plains (GP) is to access data via database" is totally wrong. None of the GP development and integrations tool , ISVs do the same, GP is an ERP, it's has it's functionality based on business rules how come you customize overriding these rules from backend? Also the link you shared is quite out dated.

Answer (score 3):

I was trolling around looking for examples of programmers shelling GP Web Services with Java and came across this article.  As responses are a couple years old this is more informational for the next person who comes across this article.

I would say interacting directly with the database to update or interact with GP is a poor choice at best.  There is an SDK dating back from the 90's where the only integration methods were direct to table and so it was fairly detailed across the modules as to how to add records.

This has been superseded twice since then by products which support the business logic.  First Integration Manger which is essentially a mapped macro program that turns off the visual UI but essentially opens client side windows and puts values in fields and presses buttons.  Better, in that you run the business logic to create or update records and can be executed by end users.

The eConnect API (maybe 2002?  started with version 8.0 though they supported 7.5) became the API standard and is still the core integration product.  It is a series of SQL stored procedures that provide the same (other than bugs) business logic as the client software and allow for easy integrations of XML documents.

GP Web Services is simply a web service wrapper on eConnect.  Additionally Integration Manager was updated to use eConnect as the engine for a large number of the integrations.

Products like Scribe, Smart Connect, Boomi all are wrappers of the eConnect logic.  As of GP2015 (earlier probably) the logic, samples, documentation all ship in full for any GP install.  If you are building your own integration then Web Services or eConnect are the products, probably best to not write directly to the database in your financial system.

Now, back to my search for Java examples using GP Web Services